# Placing a string on the clipboard without a newline

Tags: r, clipboard

I have a custom function which converts a path with backslashes on the clipboard to one with forward slashes and pastes it back onto the clipboard. The trouble is, when it is pasted back, it comes with a newline. I can't seem to find where this newline has come from as it doesn't seem to be a newline character as such:

```
btf <- function(){
  backstring <- readClipboard()
  forstring <- gsub("\\\\", "/", backstring)
  writeClipboard(forstring)
}
```

So to use a sample path: `C:\path\to\folder`
1. copy path
2. run `btf()` in R
3. paste

The pasted copy now has a newline after it. I'm running R 3.0.1 under Windows 7.
How can I prevent this newline from appearing?

Comment: From the help file: The writeClipboard function will write a character vector as text, with standard CR-LF line terminators.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

USE:

```
btf <- function(){
  backstring <- readClipboard()
  forstring <- gsub("\\\\", "/", backstring)
  writeClipboard(charToRaw(paste0(forstring, ' ')))
}
```

Comment: not sure why `writeClipboard` replaces the final character raw representation by a nul byte hence the fudge with the space.

Comment: I think that's because strings in C (used by R) are NUL terminated: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null-terminated_string